# Walkaround "Cannot update during existing state transaction" in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code snippet, which gives me an infinite loop with error message "Cannot update during existing state transaction"

```
export const Child = (props) => {
  console.log("rendering child element");

  const retrieveValue = () => {
    return "dummy";
  }

  const val = retrieveValue();
  props.callback(val);

  return (
    <p>Hello World</p>
  )
}

class App2 extends Component {
  state = {
    property: ""
  }

  callback = (val) => {
    this.setState({property: val});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>{this.state.property}</h1>
          <Child callback={this.callback}/>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

render(<App2 />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The error message makes sense, but what confuses me is why that changing the class component to function component and use the useState hook will walkaround the problem.

```
const App = () => {
  const [property, setProperty] = React.useState("");

  const callback = (val) => {
    setProperty(val);
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <h1>{property}</h1>
        <Child callback={callback}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Is there any other walkaround which let me achieve the same purpose but without using the function component?

The usecase is quite generic to me, the child component is trying to initialize some data, and somehow in certain edge case I wanna expose that data for the parent component or sibling component to render too.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-85sfgb)

Comment: Under what conditions do you want to call `props.callback`? on mount? on each render?

Comment: Here in render method, setState method is getting called when you call "props.callback(val);". So it goes into an infinite loop. shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) may help here

Comment: An `useEffect` with empty array deps or `React.memo` for Child component also could work, depending which are the conditions for call to `props.callback`

Comment: why the App functional component doesn't suffer the infinite loop though?

Answer (score 1):

Here in render method, setState method is getting called when you call "props.callback(val);". So it goes into an infinite loop.
You can use shouldComponentUpdate method here to stop repeat of rendering.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.property != nextState.property;
}
```

Comment: why the `App` functional component doesn't suffer the infinite loop though?

Answer (score 1):

@Abhijit Sil explication for infinite loop is correct. An alternative is to use `useEffect` in Child component:

```
export const Child = (props) => {
  console.log("rendering child element");

  const retrieveValue = () => {
      return "dummy";
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    const val = retrieveValue();
    props.callback(val);
  }, [])

  return (
    <p>Hello World</p>
  )
}
```